# How should I arrange my imports?

Tags: python, django

I inherited a project that has many imports. Is there any way to refactor it so that we don't have this many imports?

```
from logging import getLogger

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.forms.util import ErrorList
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseNotFound, HttpResponse, \
    HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from django.template.loader import render_to_string, select_template
from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict
from django.utils.http import urlencode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.http import require_safe

from social.core.http.urltools import fully_qualified_url
from social.group.views.util import cache_key_with_events
from social.activity.util import generate_activity_stream_for_context, \
    generate_notifications_for_user, generate_subscriptions_for_user, \
    render_my_latest_notifications, get_activity_blocks, generate_activity_stream_for_user
from social.comment.forms import create_comment_form
from social.content import content_repository
from social.content.models import Context
from social.core.thumbnail import thumb_repository
from social.event import event_repository
from social.group.models import Course, SubGroup, Program
from social.group.ical_export import users_event_list_to_ical_reponse, event_list_to_ical_json
from social.group.views.search_views import GroupMultiFacetedSearchView
from social.group.views.common_views import search_period_as_start_end
from social.post.forms import create_post_form
from social.subscription.models import Subscription
from social.subscription.tasks import date_range, daily_context_ids, \
    render_digest, weekly_context_ids
from social.users.forms import HideObjectForm, ReportAbuseForm, \
    RoleInContextNoGrantsForm, CalendarFilterForm, _external_code_choices
from social.users.models import UserProfile, Role, is_roleid_granted_to, programs_for, suggest_student_groups_as_string
from social.users.person_repository import \
    person_repository_singleton as person_repository
from social.util.models import get_object_by_generic_slug
from social.core.http.response import response_forbidden, data_to_json_response
from social.wiki import edit_views as wiki_edit_views
from social.wiki import manage_views as wiki_manage_views
from social.core.decorators import allow_jsonp
from social.users.menu_views import top_menu, _subscribed
from social.toolbar.views import _allowed_referer
from social.util.language import set_language, english_selected
from social.core.semester import get_current_semester
from social.util.notices import Notices
from social.users.user_util import is_superuser_enabled
from social.core.semester import get_semester_start_end, YearSemester
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing way too much in one file. Splitting up your file would increase maintainability and reduce the number of imports per file. How big is the original file in Lines of Code?

Comment: @Mast The file is "only" 1071 lines. So the actual size is manageable but I think there are too many imports. I think it is a good idea to split to files to increase maintainability.

Comment: That's purely subjective. The amount of imports you have here actually takes up more lines than many of my code files do. I would say you definitely need to split this up. 1000 lines is way past the point of needing refactoring; to me, a file with ~200 lines is probably the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you importing everything directly in this way? That's what's causing your problem. You realise that you can just call something like `import django.utils` and then still get access to all these things. I'm not familiar with `django` specifically, but most modules and packages can be imported with a plain import, like `import django` and then accessed. But in case `django` is an odd case you could still do `import django.utils`.

So this:

```
from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict
from django.utils.http import urlencode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

Can change to this:

```
from django import utils
```

Then you can just call on these if you prefix them with `utils`:

```
utils.datastructures.SortedDict
utils.http.urlencode
utils.safestring.mark_safe
```

And yes, you can still alias them by assignment.

```
_ = utils.translation.ugettext
```

It may mean longer calls to functions but it will clean up tons of imports and make your code clearer. When you call all these functions it reads oddly because you're not referencing the fact that they came from django. Well in this case people would notice the long list of imports, but in general using `from x import y` should be used only a bit, not as a way to get everything directly referenceable.

Answer (score 4):

Start by making sure you actually need all of those. Especially when it's a project which has had many alterations after first release it's easy to have leftovers which are no longer used.

Next thing to do is to realize you're probably doing an awful lot in the same file. The Single Responsibility Principle does not only apply to classes. If your file contains multiple classes, consider giving the biggest classes their own file.

These steps will have reduced your list of imports per file significantly while improving the maintainability of your code. If you still feel there are too many left, consider using SuperBiasedMan's answer. However, I feel `import django.utils` constructs are a code smell and should be avoided if possible. Given your current structure isn't any better, it's choosing between two evils.